# Is it possible to change the CSS with C#?

Tags: c#, html, css, z-index

I've got four div's on my page and the z-index of the div's should change if there displayed less. Now I need to know if I can change the CSS rigth inside c#.
It would be much easier like that. Because I did it with a javascript, but like that, I can't automatically say how many contents there are.

Thanks

Comment: Yes its possible to change CSS using C#, set the div as runat="server" and then set Element.className="" to desired CSS.

Comment: @Dreamweaver Can I also set an ID like that?

Comment: Please clarify if you're talking about client-side or server-side development.

Comment: yes u can set the ID using Control.ClientID also, also u need to set  ClientIDMode="Static"

Answer (score 0):

The right way would be with javascript, but if you insist just add to the divs `runat="server" id="div1"` and then on server side just add what you need div1.CssStyle.Add("z-index","100");

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.attributecollection.cssstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've already added the namespace System.Web.UI but do I need to add something more?

Answer (score 0):

You can add style to any html element in `C#` like this

```
txtName.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.ZIndex, "10");
```

You can also change other properties in the same way and if you want to apply a class than you can do this

```
txtName.CssClass = "someCSSClass";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes is it possible. There is a sample:

C# code:

```
private void btnChangeStyle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lblStyle.Style="color:red";
}
```

HTML code:

```
<label runat="server" style="color:black;">Style</style>
```